# Addition program is exiting at an unintended point

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUhtf.png)
So I have a program meant to ask the user for two numbers, then add them and write it to the console. Everything works up to line 21, I did check the output value with a break point and it does add to what i want it to. But when I use the program and enter my values, as soon as I enter the second value the program closes. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Before anyone can help you, you need to take a [tour] of stackoverflow.com, visit the [help] where you will learn [ask] questions correctly, and you need to learn all requirements for creating a [mre]. Until that happens it is unlikely that anyone will answer you.

Comment: Please add your code as text (formatted as source code) to your question. You are probably being downvoted because you used an image link to show your code.

Comment: Do not take a screenshot of your code. Paste your code in your question. Stack Overflow has the tools to do that.

Comment: My downvote was prompted by seeing "enter image description here" instead of seeing a description of the image. That tends to be a sign of someone who has no interest in making things easier for those volunteering to help.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will try that next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cin.get()` is receiving the acsii value of ENTER that you executed on line 17 and the program immediately returns 0. Perhaps you may want the user to type in a specific value like -1 to exit instead.